# laplace of $e^{2t+3}U\left(t-2\right)$

Tags: laplace-transform

I can't get my mind around this problem, I always have issues canceling out "e" values and doing laplace transform of step units

$$e^{2t+3}U\left(t-2\right)$$

Also, is there an online calculator for this type of problems? I found this site:

https://www.symbolab.com/solver/laplace-calculator/

But it gives me an error anytime unit step is used

Comment: By "$U$", do you mean the unit step function? $\qquad$

Comment: yep, unit step function

Comment: Nothing unexpected then, that online calculator gives you an error. Inverse laplase transform involves integration over complex numbers, which step function does not support. 
Are you sure that you need inverse transform and not the direct one?